# From inside Vim how to replace 2nd occurance of a pattern in all lines?

Tags: linux, unix, vim

I have lines looking like:

```
EXPORT var value
```

From inside Vim, I want to be able to convert to:

```
EXPORT var=value
```

`:%s/ /=/g` will convert both occurrences of spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

```
:%s/EXPORT \S\+\zs /=
```

`\zs` means to start the replacement  (to `EXPORT \S\+` is used to match but is not replaced).

Comment: +1 for `\zs` and I would add another +1 for the discovery of the fact that `:s/` command does not necessarily terminate with `/`. But why? Could not find an answer in the vim online help

Comment: @ves thanks. I think the last / act as a separator, therefore is optional where there is nothing coming after it.